# How to slice dataframe, find nonzero digits, assign number from zero(0) of the first nonzero(e.g. 0,1,2) up to the last nonzero digit?

Tags: dataframe, indexing, find, slice, detect

Pls. help. My goal is to find how many object is in the csv file. As you can see in the image, I have portions where nonzero digits lie. In my case I have 2 objects where 1 object has 3 nonzero digits, so there are total of 6 nonzero digits for two objects. My task is to assign index in every non zero digit(e.g. 0,1,2) and pull out the index of the highest nonzero digit. Output could be like :[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyJk0.png)for input[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E4FE.png).
Thank you very much.

Comment: Using which language ? (r, python, ... ?) Using which software ?

Comment: Hi! I am using python. Thanks in advance.